# Perform ID based averaging of one array with IDs from another array - NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays

```
 A= np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1])
 B= np.array([2,2,2,2,32,1,12,124,1,2)
 C= #mean of B's elements where A is 1
 D= #mean of B's elements where A is 0
```

How can I do this? I think it's some combination of `np.mean` and `np.ma` but I don't understand how you can calculate the mean with a mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for a generic case when you might be dealing with other such IDs/tags in `A`, like so  -

```
np.bincount(A,B)/np.bincount(A)
```

Basically, `np.bincount(A,B)` gives us the ID based summations of `B`, where the IDs are from `A`. Then, we are dividing those summations by the count of each group of IDs to get the average values per ID group.

Sample run -

```
In [12]: A
Out[12]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

In [13]: B
Out[13]: array([  2,   2,   2,   2,  32,   1,  12, 124,   1,   2])

In [14]: B[A==0].mean() # Using boolean indexing per ID and getting avg
Out[14]: 34.0

In [15]: B[A==1].mean()
Out[15]: 2.0

In [16]: np.bincount(A,B)/np.bincount(A)
Out[16]: array([ 34.,   2.])
```